# AuthenticationEntryPoint dependent on required roles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4, servlet-3.1

### Alternate titles

- How do I get the mapped `Method` from an `HttpServletRequest`?
- How to apply `WebSecurityConfig` based on `@Secured` annotations rather than paths?

### Problem

I have a Spring MVC server using `@Secured` annotations to specify the required roles for each controller method - they do not map easily onto path patterns.

Certain roles are granted via specific authentication methods (e.g. x509, Basic realm A, Basic realm B, Bearer token).

When the caller is not authenticated, the WWW-Authenticate header should not suggest things that do not grant the required roles for the method.

### Where I am

I thought the easiest way to do this was to have the HttpSecurity configured with all possible authentication methods and to `permitAll()`, delegating all the checks to the method security. However, I can only define one `AuthenticationEntryPoint` for the chain when this fails.

Thus I need to implement an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` whose behaviour depends on the roles required, but I have been unable to find a way to get that information within the `commence` method - there appear to be no methods or attributes detailing the mapped `Method` (from which I could inspect the annotations) or the required roles (in either the `request` object or the `InsufficientAuthenticationException`).

For the same reasons, a `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` won't work, as I can't get at these things in a `RequestMatcher` either.

Is there a bean floating around that will let me easily get hold of this information?

Am I even on the right track to solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the mapped Method from an HttpServletRequest

```
Method method = ((HandlerMethod) ((ApplicationContext) request
    .getAttribute(DispatcherServlet.WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE))
    .getBean("requestMappingHandlerMapping", HandlerMapping.class)
    .getHandler(request)
    .getHandler())
    .getMethod();
```

There's also a `getMethodAnnotation(Class)` on `HandlerMethod` to skip a step.

From there you can get the details of the `@Secured` annotations and find out what the required roles are.

Comment: [SPR-14071](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14071) is a request for an easier way to get there.